# react.js Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs

Here is a piece of code from my `NotificationsUnit` component :

```
tem;
notificationsType;
constructor(props)   {
    super(props);
    this.state = {notificationsType:''};
}


render() {
    this.setState({tem: 'btn btn-'});
    return(
        <div>
            <button className='btn btn-info'>
                    onClick={this.createNotification('info')}>Info
            </button>
            <hr/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But this gives me error, saying **Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**

Here is a snap :

[image: react.js set state problem,maximum depth reached]

**How can I resolve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function to the click handler instead of calling this method directly. Please keep in mind state should never me mutated directly `this.state =` but should be changed using `this.setState()`

```
class NotificationsUnit extends Component {
    state = {
        notificationsType: '',
        tem: 'btn btn-'
    }

    render() {
        const {notificationsType} = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                <button className={'btn btn-' + notificationsType}>
                    onClick={e => this.createNotification('info')}>{notificationsType}
                </button>
                <hr/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
<NotificationsUnit notificationsType="info"/>
```

result:

```
<div>
   <button class='btn btn-info'>info</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is in line 42(my side). Which means- `this.setState({tem: 'btn btn-'});` this line.

Comment: Why are you setting state in the render method, what is the expected behaviour? @MaifeeUlAsad

Comment: mainly `notificationsType`'s will be passed to this component. Like this : `<ButtonActor name="Sign In" isPrimaryButton="true" onButtonClick={this.onButtonClick} hLink="/profile"/>` Just an example, nothing to do with this problem. So before doing this, for testing - I thought it would be more fun to test with a variable and learn something , maybe.

Comment: I added an example for using props and how to add initial state (`state = `), does this help? @MaifeeUlAsad.

Comment: *info*,*success*,*warn*,*error* - this 4 types will be passed as parameter. So I have to concatenate them with `btn btn-` and render. This is my target.

Comment: I updated the example, please check it. @MaifeeUlAsad

Answer (score 1):

Never call `setState` in `render` function ,

```
render(){
  this.setState({tem: 'btn btn-'});

  return(
    ...
  )
}
```

`setState` leads to re-render of a component, if you place `setState` in render it will execute on every re-render and you will always get error

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Instead you can make use of `componentDidMount` to check this,

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.setState({tem: 'btn btn-'});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're calling `this.setState` inside of the `render` method:

```js
render() {
  this.setState({ tem: 'btn btn-' })
  // ...
}
```

Which is causing your component to re-render infinitely.

You should **never** call `this.setState` inside of `render`. Instead, if you need to update your state based on some event, create another method inside of your component and handle it there.

```js
class NotificationsUnit extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      notificationsType: '',
      tem: 'btn btn-'
    }
  }

  handleSomeEvent = (e) => {
    this.setState({ tem: 'btn btn-' + whatever })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

---

Also, one thing that I am seeing with the `onClick` handler of your button:

```js
<button 
  className="btn btn-info"
  onClick={this.createNotification('info')}
>
  Info
</button>
```

This will end up calling `this.createNotification` without even clicking the button. Instead, what you probably want to do is this:

```js
<button 
  className="btn btn-info"
  onClick={() => this.createNotification('info')}
>
  Info
</button>
```

This way, you're creating a function that will get called when `onClick` handler gets triggered, which then will call the `this.createNotification('info')` handler, resulting in a correct behavior.